# ul list not scrolling on key press but it does with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and i have an autossugest input. The problem is that i want the `<ul>` to scroll with the keyboard keys but it doesn't work. I think scrolling with arrows keys is a default behavior but the `<ul>` doesn´t do it. Here is what is happening:

[image]

If i press the down key twice:

[image]

I'm using the [typeahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) developed by Bassjobsen.

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-provide="typeahead" id="test">
```

Javascript (with JQuery.js) code:

```
$('document').ready (function () {

  $('#test').typeahead({
      source: ['algo', 'pepe', 'algo2', 'algo34', 'pepe3', 'algo42'],
      items: 'all',
      minLength: 2
  });

});
```

I set `items` to `all` to show all items in `source`. That's why i need to scroll them.

I added this inline style to the generated `<ul>`:

```
style="max-height: 50px; overflow-y: auto;"
```

So this is the code generated by Bassjobsens library:

```
<ul class=" dropdown-menu" style="max-height: 50px; overflow-y: auto; top: 73px; left: 20px; display: none;" "="">
  <li class="active">
     <a href="#"><strong>al</strong>go</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#"><strong>al</strong>go2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#"><strong>al</strong>go34</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="#"><strong>al</strong>go42</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any updates on that issue?

Comment: Have you fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Final Edit:

Alright, I started having too much fun figuring this out, and finally have (hopefully you still need the solution!) [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EV7vk/7/) is a working solution, building off of what I posted earlier. I hope it's what you were looking for!

```
$('#test').keydown(function(e) {
    if($('.dropdown-menu').is(':visible')) {

        var menu = $('.dropdown-menu');
        var active = menu.find('.active');
        var height = active.outerHeight(); //Height of <li>
        var top = menu.scrollTop(); //Current top of scroll window
        var menuHeight = menu[0].scrollHeight; //Full height of <ul>

        //Up
        if(e.keyCode == 38) {
            if(top != 0) {
                //All but top item goes up
                menu.scrollTop(top - height);
            } else {
                //Top item - go to bottom of menu
                menu.scrollTop(menuHeight + height);
            }
        }    
        //Down
        if(e.keyCode == 40) {
            //window.alert(menuHeight - height);
            var nextHeight = top + height; //Next scrollTop height
            var maxHeight = menuHeight - height; //Max scrollTop height

            if(nextHeight <= maxHeight) {
                //All but bottom item goes down
                menu.scrollTop(top + height);
            } else {
                //Bottom item - go to top of menu
                menu.scrollTop(0);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! But that's not what i want. In your solution all the elements of the list are shown an that's why you could select them. In my real app the ul has about 70 items so y need the ul to scroll and every time the ul scrolls i need the selected element to be shown.