# Div and unordered list scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why does `div` scroll with arrows key but `ul` does not do it? This is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786407/ul-list-not-scrolling-on-key-press-but-it-does-with-mouse-wheel) i have made but no one answer yet.

Comment: You ask "Why does `div` scroll with arrows key but `ul` does not do it?" Are you asking this in some sort of general sense, or are you asking why, when you use the code in your other question, this happens? If it is in a general sense then the link to your other question does not belong in this question because it is irrelevant. If the answer you are looking is about how these elements behave when used in the code you have in your other question, then this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed with @Louis. Note that my answer is given in a general sense and has nothing to do with the previous (linked) question.

Answer (score -2):

The `<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

The `<div>` tag is used to group block-elements to format them with CSS.

Taken from [w3school.com/div](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

---

The `<ul>` tag defines an unordered (bulleted) list.

Use the `<ul>` tag together with the `<li>` tag to create unordered lists.

------> it is only a structure Element whom´s Job it is to safe a structure.
Like this element comes after that element and that element over there right behind this etc.

Taken from [w3schools.com/ul](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

---

If u want an `<ul>` with scrollbars just put the `<ul>` inside a `<div>`  give the `<div>` a `width` and `height` and apply the `overflow: auto` CSS style to it.

From now on you will have youre unordered list with cool scrollbars.

Well in fact scrollbars of the div, but who cares......

there is an unordered list and there are scrollbars ;)----------